# java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: android - Android

Tags: android

I got this message error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: android
```

my snip code:

```
final URL url;
             try {
            if (parent.getParamFile() != null) {
                url = parent.getParamFile().toURI().toURL();
            } else {

url = new URL("android://com.****/assets/" + parent.getParamAssetDir() + File.separator + parent.getParamAssetFilename());


            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("SceneLoader", e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

I don't know where is my wrong.

Comment: Question, what is this code trying to do?

Comment: `don't where is my wrong.` That looks pretty clear to me. "android://" is an unknown protocol.

Comment: `my snip code:` You should show a complete function. And indeed tell what the code should do of course.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493396/how-to-reference-android-assets-across-packages

Comment: I think the error message is the independent of  another codes.

Comment: You should post the whole logcat to your question so we can tell you that for sure